# jQuery: How to create array with two values for each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this and also provide a short explanation so that I can apply it for similar cases in the future.

I have a large HTML page that is built dynamically. 
The page contains several tables with certain **divs that are editable** (contenteditable=true). These divs all have the class `"editable"`.

Now I would like to **create an array for all these divs** that contains their id and their content (text).

So far I have the following which should create unique ids for these divs with an incrementing number but I am not sure on how to create the array for this. 
Also, just out of curiosity, is there a certain term how to call such arrays with two values per item ?

**My jQuery:**

```
$('#btnSave').on('click', function(){
    var i = 0;
    $(this).closest('form').find('div.editable').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('id', 'ed' + i+1);
        if( ($(this).text != '') && ($(this).text != ' ') ){
            $(this).addClass('edited');
        }
        i++;
    });
});

// my attempt for the array (perhaps the wrong approach):
var arrEdited = new Array();
$('div.edited').each(function(){
    arrEdited.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: not `$(this).text` , it should be `$(this).text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need another loop, instead you can put it inside your first loop, inside `if( ($(this).text() != '') && ($(this).text() != ' ') )`, then push an `object` to your array instead of a value.

```
var arrEdited = new Array();
$('#btnSave').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('form').find('div.editable').each(function(index){
        //you could use the index when you use .each function
        $(this).attr('id', 'ed' + (index+1));
        if( ($(this).text() != '') && ($(this).text() != ' ') ){
            $(this).addClass('edited');
            //instead of using another loop, you can put your code here
            arrEdited.push({
                id: $(this).attr('id'),
                text: $.trim($(this).text())
            });
            //here you use an object, people call it array of objects
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! You are right, this is even better in my case - and thanks for the explanations as well. Will accept this as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Just to add: There is a dot missing in front of "attr" - I corrected this in my post.

Comment: @keewee279, It would be better to use `index` instead of `i`, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback

Comment: @keewee279, do remove `i++;` while using the code and also cache `$(this)` in a variable like `var _this = $(this);` and use `_this` in each block

Answer (score 3):

You should use `array of objects` to store the div `id` and `text` inside array.

Check this:

```
// my attempt for the array (perhaps the wrong approach):
var arrEdited = []; // [] is better than new Array()

$('div.edited').each(function () {
    // Add this div id and content in array
    arrEdited.push({
        id: $(this).attr('id'),
        text: $.trim($(this).text())
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well. Can you explain why [] is better than new Array ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an array.

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return value.
>
> > As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.

```
var arrEdited = $('div.edited').map(function(){
    return {
        id: this.id,
        text: $.trim($(this).text())
    }
}).get();
```